# Puppet hiera lookup deep merge with knockout_prefix not working

Tags: merge, puppet, lookup, hiera

My setup is:

defaults.yaml:

```
lookup_options:
  array1:
    merge:
      strategy: 'deep'
      knockout_prefix: '--'
```

first_config.yaml:

```
array1:
  - a
  - b
```

second_config.yaml:

```
 array1:
   - c
   - '--a'
```

So the expected value array is:

```
['b', 'c']
```

This is good as long as the host is not in the puppetdb.

If the host is in the puppetdb the following returns:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Is there something missing? I searched a lot of time and read the docs multiple time but cannot figure out the problem.

Maybe anyone can give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: What is your `lookup` function? Also, I would not expect the resulting value to be `['b', 'c']` under any circumstances for the data and config you specified.

Comment: My `lookkup` function is exactly what I wrote. I try to merge the values into an array configured in all my yaml files under the `array1` key.
Why do you not expect `['b', 'c']` as output?

Comment: There is no `lookup` function in your question.

Comment: `lookup_options` is merging the `array1` parameter into my Puppet class. So I don't need a lookup function because Puppet is doing this automatic.